# How do I position two divs vertically where the top one takes the remaining height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The markup is like:-

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
            <li>...
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li>Option A
            <li>Option B
            <li>Option C
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:-

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

So, basically what I want is that `bottom` `div` should touch the lower edge of the window and the rest space should be taken by `top` `div`. My current approach of setting `max-height` in `top` `div` is clearly not good since based on screen size (on mobiles) it will be either too less or big. Can I achieve this using CSS only?

Here is a jsfiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/Ldr07h2r/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with [Flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). In this case you don't have to specify an explicit `height` for the bottom `<div>`, the top one would take the remaining space:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Ldr07h2r/3/)**

```css
#parent {
    /* other declarations... */

    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
    overflow: auto; /* Up to you! */
    flex: 1;
}
```

Have a look on these properties:

- [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: One question. Why use `100vh` instead of `100%`?

Comment: @AppleGrew Generally, a percentage value of `height` is relative to the height of the box's containing block which may or may not respect to the height of viewport; But by using `vh` viewport percentage length, the element definitely would take the height of viewport. However in this particular case where the `#parent` is positioned absolutely - i.e. `fixed` - , we could avoid using `height` and/or `min-height` properties, and instead of them, use `top: 0; bottom: 0;` declarations to make it take the entire height of the viewport: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Ldr07h2r/7/)**.

Comment: I am always amazed by how easily `flexbox` solves these kinds of layout problems.

Comment: Winner! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to **position** div.bottom **absolute** and set div.top **height** 100% - div.bottom.

Your final css has to be:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    overflow: scroll;
}
.bottom { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldr07h2r/4/

Good Luck!

Comment: What if he OP does not want fixed size for bottom div??

Comment: I am not sure how could it be done, feel free to edit my post.

Comment: Thanks but in other languages the text could wrap into another line, so I can't set a fixed height. +1 for providing a solution which can work in IE8 & 9 for the unfortunate souls who need to support them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little secret: just use a gradient on the parent element...

```
#parent {background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(238, 238, 238, 0) calc(100% - 370px), rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) calc(100% - 360px)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
```

...and you won't have to muck up your code for `height` related hacks.